# Is there a way to input a date in my GETPIVOTDATA function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, pivot-table

I've been getting my values through a pivottable in another excel as expected. I'm trying to make it automatic so that the function pulls from a certain date in another cell.

My **`M27`** has the value of `2019-05-13`. If I wanted my function to choose what date to pull from a cell, how would I be able to do that?

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Sls_Fcst_GL_Local]",'[Sales and Labor CUBE.xlsx]Sales, Labor & Productivity'!$A$3,"[Time_Period].[Time_Period]","[Time_Period].[Time_Period].[Date].&[**2019-05-13**T00:00:00]","[Region_Road].[Region_Road]",
```

============================= Ideally it'd just look like this

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Sls_Fcst_GL_Local]",'[Sales and Labor CUBE.xlsx]Sales, Labor & Productivity'!$A$3,"[Time_Period].[Time_Period]","[Time_Period].[Time_Period].[Date].&[**M27**T00:00:00]","[Region_Road].[Region_Road]",
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Use appropriate syntax... similar to combining a cell, `=A2&" "&B2` would combine combine the values of A2 and B2 as a string, with a space in the middle, you need to look at M27 by appending with an ampersand in your formula, e.g., `"&M27&"`.

Answer (score 0):

=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Sls_Fcst_GL_Local]",'[Sales and Labor CUBE.xlsx]Sales, Labor & Productivity'!$A$3,"[Time_Period].[Time_Period]","[Time_Period].[Time_Period].[Date].&["&M37&"T00:00:00]","[Region_Road].[Region_Road]",

Thank you very much Cyril, it was an easy fix. Had a brain fart.